# Creating postgres schemas using psycopg cur.execute

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

My python application allows users to create schemas of their naming. I need a way to protect the application from sql injections.

The SQL to be executed reads

```
CREATE SCHEMA schema_name AUTHORIZATION user_name;
```

The psycopg documentation (generally) recommends passing parameters to execute like so

```
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=test user=postgres")
cur = conn.cursor()
query = 'CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS %s AUTHORIZATION %s;'
params = ('schema_name', 'user_name')
cur.execute(query, params)
```

But this results in a query with single quotes, which fails:

```
CREATE SCHEMA 'schema_name' AUTHORIZATION 'user_name';
> fail
```

Is there a way to remove the quotes, or should I just settle for stripping non-alphanumeric characters from the schema name and call it a day? The later seems kind of ugly, but should still work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To pass identifiers use [`AsIs`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extensions.html#psycopg2.extensions.AsIs). But that exposes to SQL injection:

```
import psycopg2
from psycopg2.extensions import AsIs

conn = psycopg2.connect(database='cpn')
cursor = conn.cursor()
query = """CREATE SCHEMA %s AUTHORIZATION %s;"""
param = (AsIs('u1'), AsIs('u1; select * from user_table'))
print cursor.mogrify(query, param)
```

Output:

```
CREATE SCHEMA u1 AUTHORIZATION u1; select * from user_table;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a boilerplate that might help.  I've used environment variables but you can use a .conf or whatever you like.

Store your connection variables in a .env file:

```
db_host = "localhost"
db_port = "5432"
db_database = "postgres"
db_user = "postgres"
db_password = "postgres"
db_schema = "schema2"
```

Load params in your app.py and assign them to variables, then use the variables where required:

```
import psychopg2
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import database

# Load your environment variables here:
load_dotenv()

db_host = os.environ["db_host"]
db_port = os.environ["db_port"]
db_database = os.environ["db_database"]
db_user = os.environ["db_user"]
db_password = os.environ["db_password"]
db_schema = os.environ["db_schema"]

# Build Connection:
connection = psycopg2.connect(host=db_host, 
                              port=db_port, 
                              database=db_database, 
                              user=db_user, 
                              password=db_password
                              )

# Build Query Strings:
CREATE_SCHEMA = f"CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS {schema};"
CREATE_TABLE1 = f"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {schema}.table1 (...);"
CREATE_TABLE2 = f"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {schema}.table2 (...);"


# Create Schema and Tables:
with connection:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(CREATE_SCHEMA)
        cursor.execute(CREATE_TABLE1)
        cursor.execute(CREATE_TABLE2)
```

Answer (score 0):

As of psycopg2 >= 2.7, [psycopg2.sql](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/sql.html) can be used to compose dynamic statements, which also guards from SQL injection.