# Unable to Create Schema with pscopg2 library in Python

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

In my python script I am attempting to create a new schema inside my Postgresql database using the following code:

```
city = "New York"

cur.execute("CREATE SCHEMA %s", (city,)) # Creates New Schema
```

When this code is run the program throws the following error:

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "'New York'"
LINE 1: CREATE SCHEMA 'New York' code here
```

For some reason the name has been inserted into quotes which causes the program to be unable to create the schema. After doing some research I am certain that the syntax I've used here is correct and I have tried using other syntax that works with psycopg2 and still receive the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `AsIs`, as follows:

```
import psycopg2
from psycopg2.extensions import AsIs

city = AsIs("New_York")

cur.execute("CREATE SCHEMA %s", (city,)) # Creates New Schema
```

Here's a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34031599/creating-postgres-schemas-using-psycopg-cur-execute) that also used this function. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Even better than `AsIs`, use [psycopg2.sql](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/sql.html).